# GITLAB Api new branch creation

Tags: api, gitlab

I am trying to create a new branch in gitlab project using API calls

As per git document i tried using 
GET /projects/:id/repository/branches
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/branches

But this is not working when I do a post webrequest I get the response as 401, Unauthorized but other Api calls are working with the same setup. Please guide me to get branch created in GITLab using API

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efkfQ.png)

Comment: you might want to remove your token from the question.

Comment: This is not my token as it is a dummy value provided by GIT LAB doc